# UITableViewCell from contentView subview

Tags: ios5, uitableview, subviews

I have created the cells with labels and using checkaMarksAccessory. The few last cells have UITextFields which can user modifi, and those have selector on UIControlEventEditingDidEnd where i want change the state of the cell to checked.

How can i get the cell in the selector? Doesn't have the object some parentView?

The way i inserting the object to cell.

```
    UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 25, 200, 30)];
    [textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(vybavaDidFinishEdit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textfield];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so the way is to use superview. The superview is component which own the object. If i want get the UITableViewCell from UITextField i used [[UITextField superview] superview].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's safe to assume `cell.contentView.superview == cell`. Might Apple change this? I doubt it. But, I don't see anywhere in the documentation that says a cell's content view is a direct subview of the cell.

If you've added a `UIGestureRecognizer` to one of your subviews of the cell's content view, then you can get a reference to the cell with:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView]];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

[Table View Animations and Gestures sample code](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) uses `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` this way.

If you must traverse superviews, I think using a function like the one below is a bit safer.

```
UITableViewCell *ACMContentViewGetCell(UIView *view)
{
    while ((view = view.superview)) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            return (UITableViewCell *)view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

But that function still assumes `contentView` is within its `cell`, which I also didn't see anywhere in the documentation.

So perhaps, the best solution is to rearchitect your code so that you don't need to get `cell` from `contentView`, or if you must, then add an instance variable from the subview of `contentView` to `cell`.